# I use the BrowserModule in one place, but I get an error that already exists

Tags: angular

When I run the project, I get the following errors:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.

I imported the BrowserModule and BrowserAnimationsModule only in the root module. I don't understand why this error shows

[image]

Comment: Maybe a third party library that you’re using?

Comment: What could it be?

Comment: Impossible to tell for me. Do you use any smaller, more niche libs maybe? Usually the error also shows the modules it’s imported in..?

Comment: Thanks MikeOne I solved this problem by removing import { NgxGalleryModule } from '@kolkov/ngx-gallery'; Because NgxGalleryModule include BrowserAnimationModule

Comment: Good one. Happy coding!

Comment: then how to use '@kolkov/ngx-gallery ?